# How do I check whether an agda term associated with a specific name relies on hole?

Tags: emacs, agda, agda-mode

For the purpose of a script I would like to query the agda compiler about the definition of a function in an agda source file. I would like to ask the question: does the function named by **X** rely on a hole, or not? (i.e. is it a "completed proof", or is it a "proof in progress"). Where **X** is the name of the function in the source file.

For example, take the following example source file:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate
  A : Set
  x : A
  y : A
  z : A  
  q1 : x ≡ y
  q2 : y ≡ z

pf1 : x ≡ z
pf1 = trans q1 q2 

pf2 : z ≡ x
pf2 rewrite q1 | q2 = refl
```

I would like to be able to determine (in my script), does `pf2` rely on any holes? In this case the answer is no.

Alternatively, suppose that file were something like:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

postulate
  A : Set
  x : A
  y : A
  z : A  
  q1 : x ≡ y
  q2 : y ≡ z

pf1 : x ≡ z
pf1 = trans q1 q2 

lemma1 : z ≡ y
lemma1 = {!!}

pf2 : z ≡ x
pf2 rewrite q1 = lemma1
```

Now the answer to the question posed above is "yes": `pf2` is incomplete because it relies on a hole (indirectly, through lemma1).

I know that I can find out the answer to the question: are there **any** functions in this agda source file that rely on holes. When we run the agda compiler on a source file, the return status will be 1 if there are "unsolved interaction metas", and the status will be 0 if everything is completed. However I would like to know the granular information of whether a **particular** function (by name) within a source file has "unsolved interaction metas".

Is there any way to do this?

I looked through the source code for the interaction mode of agda (the interface used by the agda-mode emacs code), but it seems most of the commands defined for the interaction mode rely on character ranges rather than symbols, so I haven't found a way to get this information from interaction mode.

EDIT: based on user3237465's comment, I looked into using reflection to solve this issue. It seems like it could work but there is an issue with rewrites. For example, suppose we have the following file loaded in emacs:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Agda.Builtin.Reflection

postulate
  A : Set
  x : A
  y : A
  z : A  
  q1 : x ≡ y
  q2 : y ≡ z

pf1 : x ≡ z
pf1 = trans q1 q2 

lemma1 : z ≡ y
lemma1 = {!!}

pf2 : z ≡ x
pf2 rewrite q1 = lemma1

pf3 : z ≡ x
pf3 = trans lemma1 (sym q1)

-- user3237465 suggested this macro.
-- unfortunately, normalizing `test`
-- using this macro still doesn't show
-- information about the contents of
-- lemma1
macro
  actualQuote : Term -> Term -> TC _
  actualQuote term hole =
    bindTC (normalise term) λ nterm ->
    bindTC (quoteTC nterm) (unify hole)

test = actualQuote pf2
test2 = actualQuote pf3
test3 = actualQuote pf1
```

If I type C-c C-n and enter `quoteTC pf3`, it outputs `quoteTC (trans ?0 (sym q1))`. This is what I wanted because it indicates that a the proof depends on a hole.

On the other hand, if I type C-c C-n and enter `quoteTC pf2`, it outputs `quoteTC (pf2 | x | q1)`. So it appears that the normalization process can't see past a rewrite.

Does anyone know if there is a way around this?

EDIT2: the normalization of pf2 using user3237465's macro is:

```
def (quote .test4.rewrite-20)
(arg (arg-info visible relevant)
 (def (quote x) .Agda.Builtin.List.List.[])
 .Agda.Builtin.List.List.∷
 arg (arg-info visible relevant)
 (def (quote q1) .Agda.Builtin.List.List.[])
 .Agda.Builtin.List.List.∷ .Agda.Builtin.List.List.[])
```

Comment: It should be possible to do this via [reflection](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.2/language/reflection.html): just quote a term, normalise it and search for metas.

Comment: Commands such as search (`C-c C-z`) do rely on names. So if you want to implement this new command you should look into these (the [corresponding command name](https://github.com/agda/agda/blob/master/src/full/Agda/Interaction/InteractionTop.hs#L477) in `Agda.Interaction.InteractionTop`).

Comment: @user3237465 Thank you! It appears reflection will work for my needs. I'm currently working on verifying this, and will post back here when I'm done.

Comment: @gallais Thanks for the tip. However, I wasn't able to find any way of using search commands to extract proof validity properties for a specific name.

Comment: @user3237465 I edited the question with updates about an issue I ran into while trying to use reflection to solve my problem. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: @ttbo, you need to define a `macro`, see the [`Macros`](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.5.2/language/reflection.html#macros) section of the documentation. It should be something like `macro actualQuote term hole = bindTC (normalise term) (unify hole)`.

Comment: @user3237465 Thanks. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use `actualQuote`. When I use it within a normalization window in emacs I get the same result. Should I be trying to use the macro to cause a type check error when it's applied to a proof that has a hole in it like pf2? Like, am I trying to use the macro to get `debugPrint` to print out yes/no?

Comment: @ttbo, ah, indeed, I forgot that a macro automatically unquotes a resulting term. [Here](http://lpaste.net/4181016792820350976) is a proper version. It gives a pretty strange result, though: no explicit mentions of `meta`s, only this generated *name*: `.quote-meta.rewrite-20`. I guess at this point it's better to ask the question at the Agda mailing list, so Agda developers can see it.

Comment: @user3237465 Thanks a lot for you all your help. Yes, it seems it still doesn't show any information past the rewrite unfortunately. I'll try the mailing list.

Comment: For the record: the output of normalization `quoteTC (pf2 | x | q1)` is indeed a normal form. That notation says that reduction is stuck on the postulates `x` and especially `q1` (because rewrites translate into pattern matches). If `q1` and `x` were parameters, normalization would still get stuck on them, but it would get unstuck when they’re substituted.

The reason: given an equation `f refl = hrs`, `f refl` can reduce to `rhs`, but `f x` can’t, and this often matters. Some more details at https://github.com/Blaisorblade/Agda-playground/blob/master/SoundnessOpenTermsXiRule.agda#L6-L62.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is about using reflection to solve the problem.

The thing missing from your attempt is using `getDefinition` to look inside defined functions.

Here's a complete example using agda-prelude (https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude) because I don't have time to figure out to do this with the standard library (exercise for the reader).

```
open import Prelude
open import Tactic.Reflection
open import Control.Monad.State
open import Container.Traversable
```

We need to keep track of which names we have already looked inside to avoid looping on recursive functions, so let's use a state monad.

```
M = StateT (List Name) TC

runM : {A : Set} → M A → TC A
runM m = fst <$> runStateT m []

isVisited : Name → M Bool
isVisited x = gets (elem x)

setVisited : Name → M ⊤
setVisited x = _ <$ modify (x ∷_)

anyM : {A : Set} → (A → M Bool) → List A → M Bool
anyM p xs = foldr _||_ false <$> traverse p xs
```

Unfortunately we're not going to be able to convince the termination checker that there can only be a finite number of defined functions, so let's cheat. The no-cheat option would be to set a depth limit and return true (or dont-know) if we run out of depth.

```
{-# TERMINATING #-}
anyMetas : Term → M Bool

checkClause : Clause → M Bool
checkClause (clause ps t) = anyMetas t
checkClause (absurd-clause ps) = return false

checkName : Name → M Bool
checkName f = do
  false ← isVisited f
    where true → return false
  function cs ← lift (getDefinition f)
    where _ → return false
  anyM checkClause cs
```

I couldn't resist using do-notation for `checkName` since it makes the code so much nicer. If you're not building the latest Agda from github, you can use the commented code:

```
  -- caseM isVisited f of λ where
  --   true → return false
  --   false → setVisited f >>
  --     (caseM lift (getDefinition f) of λ where
  --       (function cs) → anyM checkClause cs
  --       _ → return false)
```

```
anyMetaArgs = anyM (anyMetas ∘ unArg)

checkSort : Sort → M Bool
checkSort (set t) = anyMetas t
checkSort (lit n) = return false
checkSort unknown = return false

anyMetas (var x args) = anyMetaArgs args
anyMetas (con c args) = anyMetaArgs args
anyMetas (def f args) = (| checkName f || anyMetaArgs args |)
anyMetas (lam v t) = anyMetas (unAbs t)
anyMetas (pat-lam cs args) = (| anyM checkClause cs || anyMetaArgs args |)
anyMetas (pi a b) = (| anyMetas (unArg a) || anyMetas (unAbs b) |)
anyMetas (agda-sort s) = checkSort s
anyMetas (lit l) = return false
anyMetas (meta x x₁) = return true
anyMetas unknown = return false
```

With the `anyMetas` function we can define a macro taking a name and returning a boolean indicating if the name depends on a meta.

```
macro
  dependsOnMeta? : Name → Term → TC ⊤
  dependsOnMeta? x hole = unify hole =<< quoteTC =<< runM (anyMetas (def x []))
```

Your test case now goes through

```
postulate
  A : Set
  x : A
  y : A
  z : A
  q1 : x ≡ y
  q2 : y ≡ z

pf1 : x ≡ z
pf1 = trans q1 q2

lemma1 : z ≡ y
lemma1 = {!!}

pf2 : z ≡ x
pf2 rewrite q1 = lemma1

pf3 : z ≡ x
pf3 = trans lemma1 (sym q1)

test1 : dependsOnMeta? pf1 ≡ false
test1 = refl

test2 : dependsOnMeta? pf2 ≡ true
test2 = refl

test3 : dependsOnMeta? pf3 ≡ true
test3 = refl
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! You said "This answer is about using reflection to solve the problem." I'm curious: are there alternative ways to decide whether a term given by some top level name is a "complete" proof?

Comment: You could use Agda as a Haskell library to load the file and inspect the internal proof state. We don't have a nice API set up though, so you'd be in for a bit of source code browsing. The advantage is that this would give you an executable that you could call from a script.